# Android RelativeLayout design issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I am facing android design issue , I can't understand why it happened it is weird.

My layout code :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outgoing_layout_bubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chatrectbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            style="@style/chat_text_message_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/time"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@{chat.messageText}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/time"
            style="@style/chat_timings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@{chat.messageTime}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

preview of this code is as below : 
     [image]

I want background color change wrapping text, but it doesn't. 
I can't understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: remove **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"*, you gave parent bottom so your time text is at the bottom of the view.

Comment: thanx bro , you solved my one isssue , other remaining width of relative not wrapped with text

Comment: remove relativeLAyout as a main layout and take LInear Vertical

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran you have given right suggestion bro on just removing android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" it will be perfect.

Comment: I added my answer below, have a look, You can add **RelativeLayout** to as root and if you give RelativLayout to root view give **android:layout_alignParentRight="true"** to inner Linear so that it will go right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#555"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            style="@style/chat_text_message_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="Message "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/time"
            style="@style/chat_timings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```